# How can I get data of a particular road using HERE traffic API?

Tags: json, here-api, traffic

I'm working with the HERE traffic API and I cant understand the output data entirely.

- How can I uniquely identify a roadway?
- How can I uniquely identify a road lane?

P.S I have read their documentation, cant seem to find any information on it.

Comment: Traffic API uses the TMC format which is defined by the TISA consortium, so one has to have some knowledge about the TMC format to work with the  API. The metadata endpoint does give some information about the different elements (https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/additional-parameters.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to (developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/key-concepts.html )for understanding Traffic API input and output. You can get Traffic Data for a Specified area by providing its latitude and longitude details in Here Required Format (which is explained in the above link).